# Performance issues plotting multiple geoms on ggplot2

Tags: performance, r, plot, ggplot2

I was playing around with a piece of code and wanted to re-do a plot using ggplot2, but encountered a huge performance issue. Maybe I am doing something wrong, but looked for similar issues on the internet and found no related topic.

Using the plot function in the graphics package and adding lines in a loop works pretty fast.

Any suggestions on how can I increase performance using ggplot2 or this is the way it works?

```
library(bootstrap); data(stamp);
nobs <- dim(stamp)[1]
dens <- density(stamp$Thickness)

# this is using the graphics plot
plot(density(stamp$Thickness),col="black",lwd=3)
for(i in 1:100){
newThick <- rnorm(nobs,mean=stamp$Thickness,sd=dens$bw)
lines(density(newThick),col="grey",lwd=3)
}

# now try something similar using ggplot2
require(ggplot2)
g = ggplot(data.frame(Thickness = stamp[["Thickness"]]), aes(x = Thickness)) + geom_density()
for(i in 1:100){
newThick <- rnorm(nobs,mean=stamp$Thickness,sd=dens$bw)
g = g + geom_density(data = data.frame(new = newThick), aes(x = new), colour = 'gray')
}
g
```

It is way too slow. Afterwards a tried with 1000 loops and the virtual machine where i am running this ran out of RAM pretty fast. Again, the plot function from graphics had no problem with it.

Comment: it is much better to first collect the full dataset in a single data.frame, and add _a single layer_ of lines separated by `group` (and optionally with multiple colours / linetypes / other aesthetic). Internally this layer will result in a single call to e.g. `grid.polylines`, with much better efficiency. It will also avoid unnecessary copying and internal calculations when building the ggplot object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be faster:

```
DF <- data.frame(Thickness = stamp[["Thickness"]],group=0)
DF <- rbind(DF,data.frame(Thickness=rnorm(nobs*100,mean=stamp$Thickness,sd=dens$bw),group=rep(1:100,each=nobs)))

g <- ggplot(DF, aes(x = Thickness,group=group)) + 
       geom_density(colour="grey") + 
       geom_density(data=DF[DF$group==0,])
print(g)
```

Comment: Hi Roland, Thanks for your answer. Indeed, it is faster, but i still see the RAM consumption going up. Is ggplot2 a memory hog? Also, if after drawing it I want to add another geom, can I do it without having to redraw the entire plot?

Comment: Well, your base graphics solution only stores data in RAM for each single line. The ggplot2 solution stores the data for the whole plot and ggplot2 works with the data.frame internally. AFAIK it's not possible to add a geom without redrawing the plot.